# Update query prevent empty param from update the column

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I create API using VB.NET. I have 5 parameters. For an update query, it's not necessary to update all 5 params. It can be only 1, 2, 3, or 4. I try to run API with only two params inserts, while other 4 I left it blank.

But then the empty param update that column to empty column. This means the pervious data replace with empty String.

How do I want to prevent this happen? Below is my current code.

```
            Try
           
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(email) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(role_id) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(factory_id) Then

                Dim myResponse As New failResponceClass
                myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter

                myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE wla_user SET name = '" & name & "', email = '" & email & "', role_id = '" & role_id & "', factory_id = '" & factory_id & "' WHERE id = '" & id & "'")

                myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = mySQLConnection
                mySQLConnection.Open()
                myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                mySQLConnection.Close()

                myResponse.statusCode = 1
                myResponse.errCode = ""
                myResponse.title = l_Title_TGWLAppUser
                myResponse.desc = "TGWL App User"

                Me.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                Me.Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse))
```

Comment: Well first of, you're not using parameters.  You're using the ill-advised string concatenation method to construct your sql.  There are heaps of examples on this sight about how to properly construct SQL commands using command parameters.  Either way though, is should relatively be simple to build in conditionals based on the value of your parameters using If statements.

Comment: Why are you creating a data adapter? The whole point of a data adapter is to save all changes from a `DataTable`, especially changes of different types. If you're not calling `Update` on the data adapter then you're not even using it. If you're going to call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a command, just create the command.

Answer (score 4):

String concatenation is not inherently bad when it comes to SQL code but concatenating user-entered values definitely is. What you should be doing is using parameters for the values but using concatenation for the criteria, so you can add an arbitrary number of them to your SQL code. Here's an example that works for two columns. You can extend it to as many columns as you like:

```vb
Public Sub UpdateTable(id As Integer, column1 As String, column2 As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
          command As New SqlCommand
        Dim criteria As New List(Of String)

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column1) Then
            criteria.Add("Column1 = @Column1")
            command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = column1
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(column2) Then
            criteria.Add("Column2 = @Column2")
            command.Parameters.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = column2
        End If

        command.CommandText = $"UPDATE MyTable SET {String.Join(", ", criteria)} WHERE Id = @Id"
        command.Connection = connection
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id

        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```